# SelectedIndex missing from select with dynamically created options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select tag and add option tags via jquery.
When I select an option,  the selectedIndex attribute is missing on the  element.

I expect that after I select the option, then the select element would have the selectedIndex and the option element would have the 'selected' attribute.  This is not the case.

I tried using with and without jQuery.

```js
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("#addbtn")

// handle click and add class
var number=1;

button.on("click", function(){
 var option = $('<option >Test'+number+'</option>');
 $('#myselect').append(option);
 option.on("mousedown", function(){
    console.log('mousedown');
 })
 option.val('Test'+number);
 number++;
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
 <select id='myselect'>
 
 </select>
</div>
 <button id='addbtn'>Add Option</button>
```

Comment: Running your snippet, `document.getElementById('myselect').selectedIndex` *does* exist (and has the value `0` after adding an item). Can you show the code that makes you think it does *not*?

Comment: Paul, you are correct.  I was inspecting the DOM with Chrome dev tools.  This does not show the selectIndex for the select tag and none of the options have the selected attribute.  Thanks.